# Python Check if files exists, If Yes Update it Else Create it

Tags: python, file

I am new to Python 
**I want to check if a filename `checkzero.txt` exists**
If it does not exists, I want to write 1 in `checkzero.txt`, else I will increment it.

```
if os.path.exists("checkzero.txt"):

    f = open('checkzero.txt', 'r')
    counter = pickle.load(f)
    f.close()

    counter = counter + 1

    f = open('checkzero.txt', 'w')
    pickle.dump(counter, f)
    f.close()

else:
    f = open('checkzero.txt', 'w')
    pickle.dump(1, f)
    f.close()
```

However if I create `checkzero.txt` as an empty file, it errors with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FileBasics.py", line 8, in <module>
    counter = pickle.load(f)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 880, in load_eof
    raise EOFError
EOFError
```

Comment: If it does not exists, I want to create and write 1 in checkzero.txt, else I will increment it.

Comment: that should work fine... although its better form to use `with open(filename) as f:` then how you are doing it

Comment: This should work fine. What is the question?

Comment: 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/manabchetia/Documents/Codes/FileBasics.py", line 24, in <module>
    counter = pickle.load(f)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 880, in load_eof
    raise EOFError'

Comment: Why are you using `pickle` to store a single number?

Comment: Say `checkzero.txt` contains something invalid (not a number) - what behaviour would you expect? Replace it with `1` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to open `pickle` files in binary mode:

```
f = open('checkzero.txt', 'rb')
```

and

```
f = open('checkzero.txt', 'wb')
```

But why use `pickle` at all?

You can get the same result like this:

```
try:
    with open("checkzero.txt") as f:
        counter = int(f.read()) +1
except IOError:
    counter = 1
with open("checkzero.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(counter))
```

Comment: Thanks for ur hints. I tried as you did but I get the same errors

Comment: And you started without a file?

Comment: Yeah I have to start without a file. Thats why I wrote the ELSE part

Comment: I've just tested it here - it works perfectly. You need to be sure before running the program again that there is no file `checkzero.txt` in your current directory.

Comment: @ManabChetia: I've edited my answer to show you a different way to achieve your goal. You don't need `pickle` here.

Comment: Question closed but if @TimPietzcker can see this comment he can add another try before counter = int(f.read()) +1 as "ValueError" and there do the counter = 1 assignment again. 
That means checking both "file does not exist" and "file was created but contains something other than number or empty. Hope it helps another newbie.

Answer (score 3):

The code seems to work fine, but I get the error that you showed in your comment if the file initially exists but is empty.  Make sure the file does not already exist the first time you run your code.

Comment: Yeah same here. But if the file is present, I want to increment the content of the file and then save it

Comment: For pickle.load() to work, the file must be created with pickle.dump().  If the file is empty, it was not created with pickle.dump(), and it does not have a counter to increment.  Does something else besides this code initially create the file?  If so, it must use pickle.dump() with some initial integer value.

Comment: Also, if using pickle is not a requirement, I would go with something like Tim Pietzcker's plain text solution.

Answer (score 3):

What about this more pythonic way?

```
try:
    with open('checkzero.txt', 'rb')as f:
        counter = pickle.load(f) + 1
except IOError:
    counter = 1

with open('checkzero.txt', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(counter, f)
```

Try to open the file for reading. If it doesn't exist set the default value.

Edit: Tim answered while I worked on my answer. Of course he's right. Why use pickle at all?

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur . But i get the error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/manabchetia/Documents/Codes/FileBasics.py", line 23, in <module>
    counter = pickle.load(f) + 1
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 880, in load_eof
    raise EOFError
EOFError`